# צידה vs צָיִד? kri ksiv

Tags: grammar-dikduk, pentateuch-chumash, parashat-toldot

What is the reason for the kri ksiv in 'בראשית פרק כ''ז פסוק ג, in which the ksiv is צידה but the kri צָיִד? See http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0127.htm

I would like to know the reason for how the ksiv fits in to the pasuk and how the kri fits in to the pasuk. Please cite any sources for your answers.

Comment: In addition to the Kestenbuam Tikun Lakorim which I had suggested ina prev. Kri / Ktiv question of yours, look at www.sefaria.org. When you click on a verse, the right margin displays a list of commentaries. Usually, at least one commentary answers your question. That's where I found the answer to this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kitzur Baal Haturim on Genesis 27:3:3:

**ציד**

> צידה כתיב ה''א יתירה שלמדו ה' הלכות שחיטה וה' סימני טהרה בעוף, אינו
>   דורס. אצבע יתירה. זפק. קרקבו נקלף. אינו חולק את רגליו. ובחיה, מפרסת
>   פרסה. מעלה גרה. ואין לה שינים למעלה. קרנים. ובשרה הולך שתי וערב תחת
>   העוקץ:
>
> An extra "heh" was written at the end of the word to hint that Yitzhak
>   was teaching Esav the 5 *halachot* required in slaughtering and the 5
>   signs of recognizing a *tahor* fowl.

The rest is just explaining what the 5 signs are, and are not directly relevant to answering the question.